# Redirect visitor to login or register when clicking a link

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that redirects a user to register if they click  an attachment.

I'd like to also have the user redirected if they click any link with the following .... https://storage.ning.com/topology/rest/1.0/file/get/....

How can I alter the existing code?

```
$('.attachments li a').click(function () { 
  if ($('#xn_signout').html() != "Sign Out" || $('#xn_signout').html() == null) {
    $(window.location).attr('href', 'https://community.eflclassroom.com/main/authorization/signUp');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help... it will override all anchor tags on your page and automatically redirect the page to the url you mentioned....

```
$(a).on('click',(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  location.href="https://storage.ning.com/topology/rest/1.0/file/get/';
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works but not what I want to happen. I guess I didn't explain it correctly, clearly.   I'd like that if the user clicks any url with https://storage.ning.com/topology/rest/1.0/file/get/  they get redirected to the register page - https://community.eflclassroom.com/main/authorization/signUp   Like the code I posted which redirects user  to register if they click on an attachment.